# Accord de « ci-joint »

Tags: accord

Faut-il accorder « ci-joint » et dans quelles circonstances ? 
Le *Wiktionaire* [se contredit](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ci-joint) sur la question :

> Ci-joint est adverbial, donc invariable, quand il précède le nom qu’il détermine, comme dans les exemples ci-dessous :
>   […]
>   *Vous trouverez ci-joint copie de sa lettre.*
>   […]
>   Ci-joint peut également avoir valeur d’adjectif quand il est placé devant un nom précédé d'un article, d'un adjectif possessif, démonstratif ou numéral :
>   *Veuillez trouver ci-jointe la notification de votre convocation.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les propos du Wikitionnaire ne me semblent pas contradictoires.

Voici un substitut potentiel dont les formes adverbiale et adjective sont distinctes : « en attachement » et « attaché ». Ça aide à dénicher plus facilement les problèmes.

En reprenant le premier exemple « *Vous trouverez attachée copie de sa lettre » ne passe pas. L'explication doit venir du fait que les adjectifs se marient mal avec l'article zéro (ils sont souvent déterminants) : on dit « Marie a eu peur », mais « Marie a eu *une* peur bleue ». En revanche « Vous trouverez en attachement copie de sa lettre » passe, tout comme « Marie a eu bien peur ».

Pour le deuxième exemple, les deux formes, « Veuillez la trouver attachée » et « Veuillez la trouver en attachement », ne posent pas problème.

---

Note: Lorsque *ci-joint*, ou d'autres constructions contenant des participes passés, sont utilisés comme des prépositions, ils ne s'accordent pas :

> Ci-joint la copie de sa lettre.

Comment: Bien d'accord: le problème tient au choix un peu malheureux de l'exemple, pas à l'explication.

Comment: @StephaneGimnenez: Comment et pourquoi est-ce que *« Vous trouverez attachée copie de sa lettre » ne passe pas.* ?

Comment: @LePressentiment: c'est un avis de locuteur natif et une tentative d'explication est donnée dans ma réponse.

Comment: _en attachement_ n'est-il pas un anglicisme et, dès-lors, à éviter dans la mesure du possible?

Comment: @okiharaherbst: c'est bien possible, en l'occurrence ce n'était qu'un moyen.

Answer (score 8):

Grevisse, *le bon usage*,

> *Ci-joint*, *ci-inclus*, *ci-annexé* sont variables quand ils sont nettement adjectifs, c'est-à-dire lorsqu'ils ont la place d'une épithète ou d'un attribut du sujet avec copule.
>
> Ils sont invariables et traités comme les adverbes *ci-contre*, *ci-après* : 1) quand ils sont en tête d'une phrase averbale — 2) quand, dans le corps de la phrase, ils précèdent un nom sans déterminant.
>
> Dans les autres cas, l'usage n'est pas fixé, particulièrement quand, dans le corps de la phrase, *ci-joint*, *ci-inclus*, etc. précèdent un nom accompagné d'un déterminant.

Donc pour moi le premier exemple est bien invariable tandis que le deuxième est du cas où l'usage varie. Deux exemples où l'accord est constant : *Votre lettre est ci-jointe.* (attribut)  *Vous devinez pour qui est la lettre ci-jointe.* (après le nom, position normale de l'épithète en français)