# Pourquoi est-ce que ci-joint et ci-inclus peuvent être variables ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, adverbes

Ceci est issu de la page 34 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker.

> Ci-joint and ci-inclus are invariable when placed before the noun.

*J'ai du mal à trouver les exemples contemporains mais je tâcherai d'en trouver. Il se peut que Google Books ne montre les exemples en entier que des plus vieux livres (dû au droit d'auteur ???).*

De [la page 368](http://books.google.com/books?id=2mUOAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA368&dq=%22trouve+ci-joint%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=KXroUqWQK--ViAeauIHAAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22trouve%20ci-joint%22&f=false) de *Mein Antheil an der Politik*, Volume 2 de Hans Christoph Ernst von Gagern :

> On a lu ensuite le protocole rédigé en forme de convention, comprenant la totalité des dits arrangemens (Pas de t?). Ce protocole, tel qu’il se trouve **ci-joint** avec les tableaux, qui en font part, a été approuvé et signé.

De [la page 186](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=IyJpq3WudnMC&pg=PA186&dq=%22ecrits+ci-joints%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=63voUorYNYmriAf_moCgAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22ecrits%20ci-joints%22&f=false) de *Souvenirs de la marquise Renée* de Froulay de Créquy :

> ... j'ai cru qu'il seroit (pas serait ?) facile de
>   vous désabuser et de vous prouver , (si vous êtes
>   cet homme juste et intègre que je vous suppose)
>   que je suis plus digne de toute votre estime que
>   non pas de votre courroux, et encore moins de vos
>   persécutions; d’après ce, jetez encore les yeux
>   sur les imprimés et écrits **ci-joints**, et mettant
>   la main sur votre conscience , ...

J'ai beau me référer à http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=378832, je reste égaré. Les deux sont-ils des adverbes? Devraient-ils rester invariables tout le temps ?

**Supplément daté le 2 février 2014 :**

> Ci-joint deux exemplaires de notre produit. (phrase averbale).

La première exemple dans la réponse de Kareen est averbale (nul verbe <=> nul adverbe), ainsi **ci-joint** fonctionne en tant qu'adjectif. Ainsi, comment est-il invariable ?

> `2.` Vous trouverez ci-annexé copie de votre demande. (précède un nom sans déterminant)
>   `5.` Vous trouverez ci-annexé(e) une copie de votre demande.

`2.` renferme l'article indéfini « une » mais `5.` ne le comprend pas. Néanmoins, comment est-ce que cette différence conduit à ce que **ci-annexé** est invariable dans `2.` mais variable dans `5.` ?

Comment: Vous ne pouvez pas mélanger toutes les époques du français en appliquant les règles de la grammaire actuelle ! La marquise R. F. C. a vécu au 18ème, et H.C.E.V.G un allemand, juste un peu plus jeune qu'elle, et qui a bien le droit de faire quelques fautes de français, si tant est que ça en était à son époque. Je mets -1 pour une question qui manque de rigueur. Restez à notre époque pour l'application des règles de grammaire de notre époque.

Comment: @Istao: J'ai mise à jour mon OP pour expliciter pourquoi j'ai choisi deux exemples. Un -1 s`applique encore ?

Comment: Quel est le problème avec les exemples cités ? Ils respectent la règle que tu mentionnes.

Comment: Lié: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/accord-de-ci-joint

Comment: Pourquoi tant de votes négatifs ? Et qu’y a-t-il de si rédhibitoire dans les exemples cités ?

Comment: Je ne vois pas _tant de votes négatifs_ ?! Je n'en vois qu'un ! (le mien, je suppose) Ou alors on n'a pas le même logiciel ? Enfin moi j'ai expliqué mon vote négatif que je sache, que j'ai raison ou pas est une autre histoire... Je voudrais que les personnes qui apprennent le français d'aujourd'hui trouvent des exemples d'aujourd'hui, ou alors ne posent pas de questions sur des règles de grammaires d'aujourd'hui avec des exemples datant de mathusalem, c'est tout.

Comment: @Istao, il y a 4 votes négatifs et 3 positifs.  Ton commentaire a 3 votes positifs et celui de Stéphane en a un.  Je n'ai personnellement rien a ajouter pour expliquer mon vote négatif.

Comment: Ah merci @Unfrancophone... je mourrai moins bête maintenant que je sais lire les votes des sites stackexchange :-)

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Pourriez-vous expliciter votre vote négatif ? Je ne saisis aucune raison ?

Comment: @LePressentiment, les commentaires de Istao et de Stephane donnent une explication à laquelle je n'ai rien à ajouter.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: J'ai posé de nouveau les questions supplémentaires qui sont reliés à celles originales (ou celles de l'original) ? Est-ce que ça fonctionne ? Peuvent-elles rester dans l'OP ?

Comment: @LePressentiment: Le format de StackExchange n'est pas adapté à la discussion (qui est censé répondre au supplément  ?). Par ailleurs, je le répète, OP ne veut pas dire « question », ni en anglais, et encore moins en français.

Comment: @Stephane Dans un certain sens, oui, OP veut dire "question". OP peut signifier *original poster*, mais également *original post*. Dans ce sens, OP veut dire "question". Ce n'est pas usuel, mais bon.

Answer (score 9):

*Ci-joint*, *ci-inclus* et *ci-annexé* changent de fonction selon leur position dans la phrase. Lorsqu'ils sont placés en début de phrase averbale (phrase sans verbe),ils sont  invariables. Ils sont également invariables s'ils sont placés directement à la gauche d'un nom *sans déterminant*.

> Ci-joint deux exemplaires de notre produit.  (phrase averbale)
>   Vous trouverez ci-annexé copie de votre demande.  (précède un nom sans déterminant)

Lorsqu'ils suivent le nom, ils se comportent habituellement comme des adjectifs. Ils sont épithètes ou attributs du sujet.

> La copie ci-jointe est essentielle.
>   La copie essentielle est ci-jointe.

Dans les autres cas, l'accord est facultatif. Je crois qu'ils peuvent être considérés soit adverbes, soit attributs.

> Vous trouverez ci-annexé(e) une copie de votre demande.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Je n'ai qu'énumérer votre réponse. Prière de m'informer des inquiétudes.